# Django REST Framework: how to properly use the HyperlinkedModelSerializer url field in unit tests

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

So I have models Actor and Role and a default REST API using Viewsets and the HyperlinkedModelSerializer.

My goal: a unit test that creates a Role with an associated Actor.

My test code is currently:

```
def test_post_create_role_for_actor(self):

    # default actor
    actor = ActorFactory() 

    # inherits HyperlinkedModelSerializer
    actor_serialized = ActorSerializer(actor) 

    postdata = {
        'role': 'mydummyrole',
        'actor': actor_serialized.data['url']
    }

    ret = self.client.post(self.url, json.dumps(postdata), content_type='application/json')

    self.assertEqual(ret.status_code, 201)
    self.assertTrue(Role.objects.filter(role='mydummyrole', actor_id=actor.id).exists())
```

Now this looks very ugly to me, especially the serialization to retrieve the generated url field. In fact, I get a deprecation warning:

> DeprecationWarning: Using `HyperlinkedIdentityField` without including
>   the request in the serializer context is deprecated. Add
>   `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.

But the "url" field as generated by the serializer seems unrelated to any request. What is the proper way to fetch this field? I feel that I'm missing a concept here. Or two.

TIA!

Comment: You have to pass the request so the URL can be converted to absolute. See See http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/reverse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In preperation of the unit test, I would first insert the actor:

```
actor = ActorFactory() 
actor.save()
```

Then use Django's [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) method to get the url by using the actor's id, or whatever field you use as identifier in the url:

```
url = reverse('my_api.actor_resource', args={'id': actor.id})
```

How to reverse the url depends on how you've set up your resource, but it should be possible.

Comment: The idea is that the serialized URL should not depend on the request that generated it. Therefore, the rest framework uses the request to make the URLs absolute and not relative.